# Phalcon - Raw Query Insert Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I've got the following `INSERT` code :

```
$reservationSuccess = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery( 
    "INSERT INTO MastersReservedTime (master_id, service_id, date, time, desc)
     VALUES (:master_id:, :service_id:, :date:, :time:, :desc:)",
    array(
        'master_id' => $OrderCommit->master_id,
        'service_id' => $oneService -> service_id,
        'date' => $OrderCommit->date,
        'time' => $startTime,
        'desc' => $desc
    )
);
```

And this code generates the following error message :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token DESC, near to ')\r\n                                                                            VALUES (:master_id:, :service_id:, :date:, :time:, :desc:)', when parsing: INSERT INTO MastersReservedTime (master_id, service_id, date, time, desc)\r\n                                                                            VALUES (:master_id:, :service_id:, :date:, :time:, :desc:) (209)' in /var/www/api/v1.0/index.php:1827\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->parse()\n#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute()\n#2 /var/www/api/v1.0/index.php(1827): Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->executeQuery('INSERT INTO Mas...', Array)\n#3 [internal function]: {closure}()\n#4 /var/www/api/v1.0/index.php(1961): Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/api/v1.0/index.php on line 1827

What could cause the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desc is [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You have to escape reserved words when you are using Raw queries. To escape them in PHQL you have to wrap them in square brackets [].

Rewriting your query like this will work:

```
INSERT INTO MastersReservedTime (master_id, service_id, date, time, [desc])
VALUES (:master_id:, :service_id:, :date:, :time:, :desc:)
```

Note the `[desc]` above.

Info from the docs: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#escaping-reserved-words

Comment: yep, that's it! Низкий поклон, до земли!

Answer (score 1):

Please, try use `desc` instead `desc`.

Comment: INSERT INTO MastersReservedTime (master_id, service_id, date, time, 'desc') - didn't help*( now error :           Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\\Mvc\\Model\\Exception' with message 'Syntax error, unexpected token STRING(desc), near to ') VALUES (:master_id:, :service_id:, :date:, :time:, :desc:)', when parsing: INSERT INTO MastersReservedTime (master_id, service_id, date, time, 'desc')

Comment: nono, not ', use \` - it below escape button on your keybord.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got problem because you are using [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).
Best solution it is add some prefix for columns.